# Element drop from behind a header

Tags: css, jquery-animate, transition

I have a banner as a .png and I want it to descend from behind a header after a click. This is what i tried, but the div in this case comes back to its original position. I want it to be behind the header (hidden) and after the transition, to maintain its position:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
position:relative;
animation:myfirst 5s linear 2s;

-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s linear 2s;

}

@keyframes myfirst
{
0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
100%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
}


@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
100%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


 <div></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I also tried with jQuery's slideDown() but sadly since it's an image it doesn't look well enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery solution, and maybe someone can come up with a more elegant one, but give it a try. I hope this is the behavior you're after.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/Qhrnd/

***HTML***

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="banner">banner</div>
```

​

***CSS***

```
div#header
{
    background: #abc;        
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
div#banner
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    background: url('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-color: #345;
}​
```

​

***Javascript/jQuery***

```
var hidden = true;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#header").click(function () {
        if (hidden)
        {
            $("#banner").animate({
                top: '+=100',
                display: 'block' //updated

            }, 500);
            hidden=false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("#banner").animate({
                top: '-=100'
                display: 'none' //updated
            }, 500);
            hidden=true;
        }

    });
});​
```

Comment: i cant because i have the .png in display = none, an here its hidden

Comment: So why don't you change the banner (your .png) to `display:block` in the `if..else..` I gave you?
(I will update my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **z-index property**

```
@keyframes myfirst{  position:absolute; z-index:-1; }
```

use z-index:1 to make visible

Check CSS z-index property

Comment: but what about the position?